# Could not find backup for factory jakarta.faces.context.FacesContextFactory

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi

I am struggling to get a simple Hello World app to run on Eclipse using the latest versions of Spring Boot, CDI, JSF and Primefaces.

Here is the error message I get when starting the application:

```
2023-04-10T02:05:29.078+02:00  INFO 17656 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.7]
2023-04-10T02:05:29.288+02:00  INFO 17656 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2023-04-10T02:05:29.295+02:00  INFO 17656 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-04-10T02:05:29.296+02:00  INFO 17656 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 983 ms
2023-04-10T02:05:29.612+02:00 ERROR 17656 --- [           main] jakarta.faces                            : Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
2023-04-10T02:05:29.615+02:00 ERROR 17656 --- [           main] jakarta.faces                            : Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: jakarta.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. Attempting to find backup.
2023-04-10T02:05:29.615+02:00 ERROR 17656 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Servlet.init() for servlet [facesServlet] threw exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory jakarta.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.notNullFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:496) ~[jakarta.faces-api-4.0.1.jar:na]
    at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:190) ~[jakarta.faces-api-4.0.1.jar:na]
    at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:263) ~[jakarta.faces-api-4.0.1.jar:na]
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.acquireFacesContextFactory(FacesServlet.java:493) ~[jakarta.faces-api-4.0.1.jar:na]
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:342) ~[jakarta.faces-api-4.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:808) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.load(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:84) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:3215) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.lambda$deferredLoadOnStartup$0(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:67) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.doWithThreadContextClassLoader(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:108) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.performDeferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatWebServer.java:305) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:216) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:44) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:587) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.psbase.test.Main.main(Main.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
```

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.psbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test Maven Webapp</name>
    <description>Manages Expenses</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the TestBean.java:

```
package com.psbase.test;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;


@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean{
    
   private String text;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        text = "Hello World!";
    }

   public String getText() {
       return text;
   }
   public void setText(String text) {
       this.text = text;
   }

   public void handleKeyEvent() {
       text = text.toUpperCase();
   }

}
```

Here is the Main.java:

```
package com.psbase.test;

import java.util.Arrays;

import jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.Servlet;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main{

  public static void main (String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  ServletRegistrationBean<Servlet> jsfServletRegistration (ServletContext servletContext) {
      //spring boot only works if this is set
      servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());

      //registration
      ServletRegistrationBean<Servlet> srb = new ServletRegistrationBean<Servlet>();
      srb.setServlet(new FacesServlet());
      srb.setUrlMappings(Arrays.asList("*.xhtml"));
      srb.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      return srb;
  }
}
```

I tried to use older version of the dependencies, so that I use javax instead of jakara, or so that I use @ManagedBean annotations instead of @Named annotation (that use CDI). Also I tried different embedded web container (beside Tomcat)

When not using the latest version, my code at least runs, alhtough the data in the XHTML view are not displayed like they should (as if the EL did not work)